# Firebase onAuthStateChanged conflicts with my explicit login method, making two calls

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So my `onAuthStateChanged()` listener logs users in automatically if they've logged/signed in before. It uses `setUser()` to set a uid and userData in a global react state after fetching it from Firestore (I use this to check if user is authenticated for certain app screens). If fetching userData fails, then we sign-out instead.

The problem is that my `loginUser()` method does the same thing. It uses email/password to get uid and userData from Firestore. So when I sign-in, it creates two api calls to fetch userData (because `onAuthStateChanged()` and `loginUser()` both get called).

How do I make sure there is only one call?

Another issue is with signup. I create a user doc in Firestore linked to every new user during sign-up. `onAuthStateChanged()` gets called before this doc is created and when it tries to fetch userData, it acts as if it failed since the doc doesn't exist yet. This means my code signs out the user and forces every new user to login a second time before auth persistence kicks in.

Is there a way to makes sure `onAuthStateChanged()` is only called when I want to re-authenticate a user? Or do I have to redesign my auth-flow? (if I do, please recommend an effective redesign)

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), async (curUser) => {
            if (curUser && !Object.keys(user.userData).length) {
                const uid = curUser.uid;
                const token = curUser.accessToken;

                // Set access token for authorizing backend calls
                await apiClient.setToken(token);

                // Then get the user account specifc data
                const loginRes = await apiClient.GET({
                    endpoint: "me",
                    params: { uid: uid },
                });

                if (loginRes?.data) {
                    setUser({
                        uid: uid,
                        userData: loginRes.data,
                    });
                } else {
                    // If there was an error fetching user data, then we want to sign them out
                    console.log("Signing out user using authstatevhanged")
                    await apiClient.signOutUser();
                }
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

```js
async loginUser(credentials) {
        // Sign in a user using email and password
        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            credentials.email,
            credentials.password
        )
            .then(async (userCredential) => {
                const uid = userCredential?.user?.uid;
                const token = auth?.currentUser.accessToken;

                // Set access token for authorizing backend calls
                await this.setToken(token);

                // Then get the user account specifc data
                const user = await this.GET({
                    endpoint: "me",
                    params: { uid: userCredential.user.uid },
                });

                // If fetching user data was successful, return user data and auth token (uid)
                if (user?.data) {
                    return {
                        data: { uid: uid, userData: user.data },
                        errorCode: null,
                        errorMessage: null,
                    };
                } else {
                    // If there was an error fetching, return an error. Make sure to remove all sensitive data/tokens
                    // For example, the access token and auth's currentUser set by signInWithEmailAndPassword
                    // we need to do this in case signInWithEmailAndPassword() succeeded, but getMe() failed,

                    // This removes auth?.currentUser
                    signOut(auth).then(async () => {
                        // This removes the accessToken from local storage
                        await this.removeToken();
                    });

                    // Finally we return an error for the UI to notify
                    return {
                        data: null,
                        errorCode: user?.errorCode,
                        errorMessage: user?.errorMessage,
                    };
                }
            })
            // If the user failed the login, then return an error
            .catch((error) => {
                // Example of error object: {"code":"auth/invalid-email","customData":{},"name":"FirebaseError"}
                const errorCode = error.code;

                // Possible codes:
                // auth/invalid-email ---> invalid email
                // auth/wrong-password ---> wrong password
                return {
                    data: null,
                    errorCode: errorCode,
                    errorMessage: errorCode,
                };
            });
    }
```

Comment: You can move the onAuthStateChanged listener inside the login method and fetch the data there.

Comment: @Muhammad Hamid Rafique But will my user data get fetched if the user does not explicitly log in?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @MuhammadHamidRafique's comment, it sounds like you want to register the `onAuthStateChanged` listener only once the user explicitly signs in - in the `then` block of your `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Note that having or *not* having an `onAuthStateChanged` listener doesn't change how the Firebase SDK behaves though: it will still restore the user credentials from local storage, authenticating the user that was previously signed in. If you want to prevent *that*, consider [disabling auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) .

Comment: I don't want to register {onAuthStateChanged} only when the user explicitly signs in. I register the {onAuthStateChanged} listener at a high level page and it wraps the whole app. I want to fetch userData without having the user explicitly sign in if Firebase SDK had stored the user's credential locally during a previous session. I want to use {onAuthStateChanged} to fetch user data using those persisted credentials.

Comment: Would a good alternative be having the {onAuthStateChanged} handle all the data fetching and removing that duplicate logic inside {loginUser()}? The problem with {signIn()} still persists because my newly created doc will fail to get fetched from Firestore.

Comment: When you login your onAuthStateChanged listener will get called so if you are fetching the data in onAuthStateChanged callback, how will fetching your user related doc fail?

Comment: @Deland Having or not having an `onAuthStateChanged` listener doesn't change how the Firebase SDK behaves though: it will still restore the user credentials from local storage, authenticating the user that was previously signed in. If you want to prevent that, consider [disabling auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) altogether.

Comment: @MuhammadHamidRafique Will it also restore my React states though? Because if I don't have onAuthStateChanged, I won't technically be 'authenticated' unless my user states are restored. Which is why I need the listener to do that for me.

Comment: The user will be restored regardless of having an `onAuthStateChanged ` listener, but without an `onAuthStateChanged` listener the UI will not be updated automatically.